# Recover static library from executable

Tags: c, linker, compiler, reverse-engineering

I have an existing executable for which a small amount of source code has been lost. In particular, the executable uses a few functions from a static library, and the source code for that library is missing. I do have an older version of that library's code, but the executable uses three or four methods that aren't in the old version. I have a header file for the new version of the code, which includes prototypes of the missing functions, but the `.c` file containing the actual function definitions is missing.

Since the executable is statically linked, I wonder if there is a way to rebuild the static library by extracting the object code from it. I can find the symbols I need using `nm` and `objdump`, but I don't know if there's a way to extract those functions and re-package them into object files or a static library.

As an example, it looks something like this:

```
$ nm ./theApplication
<a bunch of stuff>
001721dc T _missingFunction1
<more stuff>
00171ed8 T _missingFunction2
<more stuff>

$ objdump --disassemble-all ./theApplication
<a bunch of stuff>
00171ed8 <_missingFunction2>:
  171ed8:       1a e5 f8 14     P2 = [P3 + 0x53e0];
<more stuff>
001721dc <_missingFunction1>:
  1721dc:       c5 04           [--SP] = (P5:5);
<more stuff>
```

I'd like to pull `missingFunction1()` and `missingFunction2()` out into a static library or object files so I can link against them in other executables. Is that possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32372992/3684433), which is kind of similar and seems to imply that it's not possible. I don't think I understand the linking process well enough though. Why wouldn't the relocation process be reversible? Wouldn't you basically just clear the address and put in an arbitrary placeholder?

Comment: "for which a small amount of source code has been lost"?the simplest way is to ask the author to replace the missing source. if you cant ask them, you are stealing it.

Comment: @robert I agree that that's the simplest solution. But if the author is dead, I still need to figure this out. Some clients don't take great care of their IP. I'm just trying to help here.

Answer (score 1):

If the executable you're inspecting was built with DEBUG enabled, you'll find lots of info detailing source and header files used for compilation, including directory locations where those files originated, the original compile command including all arguments, tons of info, using just `objdump` and few options...

#### Compile Info

`objdump -Ws --dwarf=info --dwarf-depth=1 <EXE_FILE>`

This command generates output in DWARF format, don't worry about what that means just search for tag `DW_TAG_compile_unit` in the output, you'll find many instances like this revealing source file, compile command, lots of useful info for your investigation.

```
   <526a1>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <526a2>   DW_AT_name        : calculate_tax_rate.c
    <526ad>   DW_AT_language    : 12  (ANSI C99)
    <526ae>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : /opt/src/modules/calc/
    <526d2>   Unknown AT value: 2205:  /opt/gnu/bin/cc -V -m64  -I/opt/hdr/include -L/opt/sqlserver/lib -L/opt/DBG/bin/utils -xc99=all -m64 -c -o MESG_UTIL.o MESG_UTIL.c
    <52813>   Unknown AT value: 2207: Xa;R=HPUX C 3.11 HPUXOS 2004/06/02;
```

#### Directory Table Info

`objdump -Wl --dwarf=info --dwarf-depth=1  <EXE_FILE>`

This command details directory table information for source and header files; search for tag `The Directory Table` in the output:

```
 The Directory Table:
  /opt/src/modules/calc/
  /usr/include

 The File Name Table:
  Entry Dir     Time    Size    Name
  1     1       0       0       calc.c
  2     1       0       0       debug.h
  3     2       0       0       calc_math.h
  4     2       0       0       calc_math.c
```

#### Intermix Source Line #s with Assembler Instructions

This command disassembles the .text (code) section and correlates source line numbers with respective assembler instructions. This is really getting in the weeds, but you *could* technically recreate the original source behavior by reverse engineering for each respective line, per source file. Yeah, that's a fun project :-). Hope it helps

`objdump -Ddlw --section=.text <EXE_FILE>`

```
/home/projects/src/modules/calc/calc.c:476
   1000364f0:   e0 5f a7 af     ldx  [ %fp + 0x7af ], %l0
   1000364f4:   e0 77 a7 df     stx  %l0, [ %fp + 0x7df ]
/home/projects/src/modules/calc/calc.c:477
   1000364f8:   e0 5f a7 b7     ldx  [ %fp + 0x7b7 ], %l0
   1000364fc:   e0 77 a7 d7     stx  %l0, [ %fp + 0x7d7 ]
/home/projects/src/modules/findrates.c:4434
   100036500:   e8 5f a7 df     ldx  [ %fp + 0x7df ], %l4
   100036504:   e2 5f a7 c7     ldx  [ %fp + 0x7c7 ], %l1
   100036508:   e0 57 a7 eb     ldsh  [ %fp + 0x7eb ], %l0
   10003650c:   a7 2c 30 03     sllx  %l0, 3, %l3
   100036510:   e8 74 40 13     stx  %l4, [ %l1 + %l3 ]
/home/projects/src/modules/calc_encrypt.c:480
   100036514:   e8 5f a7 d7     ldx  [ %fp + 0x7d7 ], %l4
   100036518:   e2 5f a7 c7     ldx  [ %fp + 0x7c7 ], %l1
```